# Using ruby on rails validation helpers inside custom validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, helper

Let's say I have lots of attributes that can only have a specific set of string values.

Typically we'd see the following.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
   validates :foo, inclusion: { in: ['some', 'array'] }
   validates :bar, inclusion: { in: ['another', 'array'] }
   validates :moo, inclusion: { in: ['one_more', 'array'] }
end
```

I have lots of these types of validations in my model and I want to DRY them up. So I tried the below but I get a error `undefined method 'validates' for #User:0x00007fdc10370408`.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  VALIDATION_ENUMS = {
    foo: %w[foo1 foo2],
    bar: %w[bar1 bar2]
  }.freeze

  validate :validate_enums

  def validate_enums
    VALIDATION_ENUMS.each_key do |attribute|
      validates attribute, inclusion: { in: VALIDATION_ENUMS[attribute] }
    end
  end
end
```

How do I get access to the ActiveModel::Validations helper methods from within my function?

Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Remember that `validates` is a class method, only executed once when the class is loaded to establish what will be validated.  `validate` is calling an instance method.

A better way might be to execute the DRY code immediately when loading the class.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
 validate_enums = {
    foo: %w[foo1 foo2],
    bar: %w[bar1 bar2]
  }.freeze

   validate_enums.each do |key, array|
     validates key, inclusion: { in: array }
   end
```

Note that as you don't reference `validate_enums` ever again, you don't need to make it a class constant, which is why I didn't.

But you don't really save any lines and add complexity, so I'd stick with the explicit `validates`, myself.

Comment: `freeze` is unnecessary as well since this is a local variable and reasonably speaking completely inaccessible to modification.

Comment: I fully agree here that it just adds complexity. Especially if later on if you have to add options to to call like `if:`, `unless:` or `on:`.

Answer (score 0):

This approach won't fly. The validation methods are class methods that modify the class itself while you are writing an instance method that get called on an instance of the class when `#valid?` is called.

If you want to dynamically add existing validations to the class you need to create a class method:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  def self.add_inclusion_validations(hash)
    # don't use each_key if you're iterating over both keys and values
    hash.each do |key, values|
      validates_presence_of key, in: values
    end
  end

  add_inclusion_validations(
    foo: %w[foo1 foo2],
    bar: %w[bar1 bar2]
  )
end
```

Of course you could also just skip the method completely:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  {
    foo: %w[foo1 foo2],
    bar: %w[bar1 bar2]
  }.each do |key, values|
      validates_presence_of key, in: values
  end
end
```

If what you instead want is to write a validation method that uses the existing functionality of other validations you would create a `ActiveRecord::Validator` or `ActiveRecord::EachValidator` subclass and use the existing validations there. But you really need to start by [reading the guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#custom-validators) and API docs so that you have a base understanding of how that works.